# How to clear the sessionstorage on browser refresh in Aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, session, init

I am using sessionStorage.clear() to clear the sessionStorage in Init method, but this one is clearing after clicking 2 times on refresh button of the browser, is there a way we can clear after clicking 1 time?
This is the component A:
Here I am setting the data in session storage in the handleChange method:

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper){
     sessionStorage.setItem('id',"data");
}
```

This is the component B:
Here in this component I am getting the data from sessionStorage in doInit method:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
if(sessionStorage.getItem('id')){
        var msg = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
        component.set("v.receivedmessage",msg);
        sessionStorage.clear();
        }
}
```

But once I refresh the browser page, the data should be cleared, but its clearing after clicking 2 times on refresh button of the browser, is there a way we can clear the data after clicking 1 time on refresh button?

Comment: You'd have to show us some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have edited the question

Comment: @SagarHerakal, are you sure handleChange is not sometimes called after page refresh (and after clearing the session)? I'd set a breakpoint in this method. Are you sure sessionStorage.clear() is called _each time_ you refresh your browser? Set a breakpoint on this line too. And rather out of curiosity I'd try to uncheck "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" in the Setup (if you haven't done already), although this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @FelixvanHove, thanks for your valuable suggestion, I did not set a breakpoint, Now I am able to resolve it